# Why is it that not all metals produce hydroxides when reacting with water?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, metal, transition-metals, decomposition, alkali-metals

I was taught, as a rule, that:

> metals + water $\rightarrow$ metal hydroxide + hydrogen gas

$$\text{Na} + \text{H}_2\text{O} \rightarrow \text{NaOH} + \text{H}_2$$

---

However:

$$3\text{Fe} + 4\text{H}_2\text{O} \rightarrow \text{Fe}_3\text{O}_4 + 4\text{H}_2$$

Why is this so? Why isn't $\ce{FeOH}$ produced? Is it because $\ce{FeOH}$ is unstable and it thermally decomposes the moment its formed?

Comment: There is no compound called FeOH.

Comment: Many rules taught at lower education levels are simplified, often oversimplified and have ( often many ) exceptions. They definitely cannot be taken as laws, because exceptions are behind near every corner.

Comment: Anyway the stability of $\ce{Fe3O4}$ is something like a challenge, because it contains two atoms $\ce{Fe}$ with oxidation number $+3$ and one $\ce{Fe}$ with oxidation number $+2$. This is hard to justify.

Comment: Not even talking about many metals ( like gold and platinum ) which do not care about water. IMHO, the author of the above rule should reassess his/her teaching abilities, unless it is quoted out of proper context. As metals reacting by the mentined way are rather exceptions than rule.

Comment: This question is well asked, unfortunately the duplicate is not. But that is the one that covers your question. You still get a +1 from me, but I also will close the question.

Comment: Most likely, the initial deprotonation of water gives the hydroxide. But if the reaction requires high temperature and the hydroxide is not strongly thermally stable, it could go over to the oxide. **The boundary is actually not sharp;** see [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/132511/17175).